# Django - replacing string in whole project

Tags: python, django, string, performance, replace

Currently I m creating quite big project and I need to implement functionality which will replace string with string provided by user. Moreover each of user can have his own custom string. I will give example for better understanding

there is a string "object" and user1 want to change string "object" to "tree", in whole project (all templates etc) string "object" is replaced by "tree"

My ideas are as folllow:

1. Creating middleware which would replace strings
2. Creating js plugin
3. Creating blockreplace(something like blocktrans) which would replace strings only in block ( I would also need to connect it with trans)

Do you have any other ideas which would be better? And which idea for you is the best option?

**Examples**:

Text in template main.html

...
this **object** is very useful
...

and every user can personalize site by his custom string

- user1 wants "tree" instead of "object"
- user2 wants "apple"
- user3 wants "grape"

They save their settings and then when they enter main.html they see

- user1: this **tree** is very useful
- user2: this **apple** is very useful
- user3: this **grape** is very useful

hope it helps

Comment: What do you mean by "string" ? Could you provide some code samples ?

Comment: Sure, As string I meant text which occur in my project. I added better examples to question

Comment: How uber do you need this? Do the users decide which strings they want to replace or can you tell me in advance what's changeable and what's not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinkig about this question I came to conclusion that the best option is the one with middleware.

```
class CustomWordsMiddleware(object):

   def process_response(self, request, response):

       if request.user.settings == 'lumberjack':
           response.content = response.content.replace("object", "tree")
           response.content = response.content.replace("objects", "trees")

       return response
```

Of course it is just example, I will also implement regexp instead of string replace. Moreover, I will use beautyful soup for parsing html to find classes where I should replace strings.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I think something wrong with your project if you have to do this. Did you consider using variables?

Under Linux, this command will replace "orange" to "whale" in all files under current directory

```
find -type f -exec sed -i s/orange/whale/ {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ;) But I do not want to change strings constantly. I just want to add functionality which will help to personalize my site for users. Goal is that every user can have his own strings (dynamic content)

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use a variable. And maybe a class in your model to associate an object with you user ?

Comment: It would be great and simple solution, to be honest I haven't even thought about it... However, I want to allow user to pick any word from list (which can contains a lot of strings), so it would be hard to use so many variables in templates without losing sense of sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 scenarios base your question

1. A user can replace any string in the templates. (Here I am assuming strings can only be replaced in templates)
2. Or you have predefined collection of strings which user can change or overwrite.

If your problem matches scenario 1 then it is very difficult to implement any simple and clean solution to solve your problem. May be you can give users an HTML editor to rewrite the contents of template.

But if your problem matches scenario 2 then you can put all these pre-defined keywords in any persistent storage in the form of key:value pairs and when a user logged in then load these key:value pairs for that user in memory. And make your templates get the values of predefined keys from the memory (may be through Django [contextprocessor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)).

Answer (score 0):

This is more like an project architecture problem.
The best way of doing what i "think" you want is to:

1. create a list of the "strings" options in a database.
2. In the user model create a field like "chosen_string"
3. When the user selects the option to be used (the string) you just update the user model
4. whenever you want to use the strings , just do a query.